# Is it possible to render a page with background-color = transparent

Tags: abcpdf

I'm using ABCPDF 8 to generate images (.PNG) from HTML:

```
theDoc.AddHtml("FooBar HTML text")
theDoc.Rendering.GetData(".PNG")
```

That works fine except of one little problem:

I want to show such an image in front of another graphic. Therefore it must have a transparent background, but it always have a white background.

Is it possible to make the Page background transparent?

Kind Regards,
Mar

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
theDoc.AddHtml("FooBar HTML text")
theDoc.Rendering.SaveAlpha = true
theDoc.Rendering.GetData(".PNG")
```